# Read Jasypt password from database to validate

Tags: java, encryption, jasypt

I am playing around with a login/register system for a desktop application. I have a register form and sign in form and the credential information is saved to a PostgreSQL database. I started out without encrypting information and everything is working but I now want to encrypt the password to save to the database. I am using Jasypt and got the password to encrypt and save to the database:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource() == registerButton){
        try{
            //connects to the database
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cc","pi","server");
            //inserts values into table
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("insert into users values(?,?,?,?,?)");
            statement.setString(1, firstName.getText());
            statement.setString(2, lastName.getText());
            statement.setString(3, email.getText());
            statement.setString(4, username.getText());
            //checks password to ensure confirmation matches
            //encrypts password for storing in database
            if(password.getText().equals(confPass.getText())){
                StrongPasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor = new StrongPasswordEncryptor();
                String encryptPass = passwordEncryptor.encryptPassword(password.toString());
                statement.setString(5, encryptPass);
                statement.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registered Successfully");
                frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
            }
            else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password did not match");
            }
        } catch(SQLException f){
            f.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This works well and my password is encrypted. I am stumped on where to begin with getting the password from the database to compare the encrypted password to the user input. My sign in form to compare passwords (prior to encrypting the password):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    //verify users credentials and signs in
    if(e.getSource() == login){
        try{
            //connects to the database
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cc","pi","server");
            //inserts values into table
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT username, user_pass FROM users WHERE username = ? and user_pass = ?");
            statement.setString(1, username.getText());
            statement.setString(2, password.getText());
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();
            if (result.next()) {
                frame.dispose();
                new CommunityCooks();
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username or Password did not match.");
            }
        }
        catch(SQLException f){
            f.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I made a test app to compare encrypted passwords and have a general idea of how it works:

```
import org.jasypt.util.password.StrongPasswordEncryptor;

public class EncryptTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userPass = "test";

        StrongPasswordEncryptor passwordEncryptor = new StrongPasswordEncryptor();
        String encryptPass = passwordEncryptor.encryptPassword(userPass);
        System.out.println(encryptPass);

        if(passwordEncryptor.checkPassword("test", encryptPass)){
            System.out.println("correct");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("wrong");
        }
    }
}
```

The part that I am stumped on is trying to get the encrypted password and compare it to the user input password to validate. I believe I need to encrypt the input password and then can use the passworEncryptor.checkPassword(); but I don't know exactly where to put that in the sign in code and how to implement it. Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the Java library Jasypt is shortened for "Java Simplified Encryption" and so this library is trying to avoid that
users are making implementations of crypto-routines that become insecure because of implementation errors.

The validation of a user password is as simple as your test app - you do not need to implement an encryption part, just pass the
password the user typed in your login form and pass it to the validation part

In details: There are two parts - in part 1 the user registers with his userPassword and passes it to the encryptPassword method:

```
String userPassword = "myPassword";
String encryptedPassword = passwordEncryptor.encryptPassword(userPassword);

encryptedPassword example: rCAgedhPnGoDZ1PF7hgspDIhLnLAHo536PSCKUfpYu8Yv0JHEcIZ3ZVHIHojBn1D
```

This encrypted password get stored in the database and you have to keep in mind that you cannot restore the original password from this string!

In part 2 the user tries to login with his loginPassword and passes it to the checkPassword method. The program loads the encryptedPassword from the database and passes the loginPassword together with the encryptedPassword. The result (boolean) is checked and the next steps in your program depend on the result, "true" means that the loginPassword is correct and "false" means that the loginPassword is not correct.

```
String loginPassword = "myPassword";
if (passwordEncryptor.checkPassword(loginPassword, encryptedPassword)) {
      // correct!
      System.out.println("correct passsword");
} else {
      // bad login!
      System.out.println("password not correct");
}
```

For more information you can check the "Easy usage" webpage: http://www.jasypt.org/easy-usage.html

Comment: I understand how that works. I made a test app that and posted that as well that shows it working. The issue that I am having is how to get the encrypted password from a database and compare it to the password that the user has input. When I use the preparedStatement to get the encrypted password, I am not sure where to go for that and the Jasypt site doesn't talk about that.

Comment: The password.encrypter-method of Jasypt is a one way encryption function, means you cannot "restore" the password once it's encrypted. There is only the way to verify a (later) input against the encryptedPassword and that is done in part 2. Again: you cannot "compare" the two passwords.